# Pass a value to constructor on instance registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a class `CmsService` that handles CMS related stuff. For simplicity's sake, say that it has this single constructor:

```
public CmsService(Site site)
{ .. }
```

`Site` is an enum (Site X, Y, or Z) and is used by the service to determine for which site is has to add and retrieve pages, rebuild the sitetree, etcetera.

Obviously, when using this service in Site X, I want to resolve it using Site.SiteX as its constructor parameter:

```
public PagesController(CmsService cmsService /* how can I pass SiteX here? */)
{ .. }
```

This is my Castle DI registration:

```
container.Register(Component.For<CmsService>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

I imagined something like this would be possible:

```
container.Register(Component.For<CmsService>().ForParameter("site", Site.SiteX).LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

However, I've been playing with `DependsOn` and `DynamicParameters` but I couldn't get it to work. So a concrete example would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the [Typed Factory Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) to pass a `CmsService` factory into the `PagesController` constructor, and create the `CmsService` there.

Define the factory interface (no implementation needed):

```
public interface ICmsServiceFactory
{
    CmsService Create(Site site);
}
```

Include the facility:

```
kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
kernel.Register(
                Component.For<ICmsServiceFactory>()
                         .AsFactory()
               );
```

Change your `PagesController` constructor:

```
public PagesController(ICmsServiceFactory cmsServiceFactory)
{
    this.cmsService = cmsServiceFactory.Create(Site.Sitex);
}
```

Note that the `CmsService` constructor's `Site` parameter must be named *site* for the factory to match the arguments.

Comment: Hadn't thought about this approach. Nice one! Works for me :-)